# Changing default Dropbox at command line to a business account from a personal account on macOS

Tags: command-line, mac, zsh, dropbox

I've linked to my business Dropbox on my Mac which already had my personal Dropbox installed. I can easily access both my Dropbox (Personal) and Dropbox (Business-name) from the Finder.

At the command line (in .zsh), doing an `ls` I see the following:

- `Dropbox` (listed in purple),
- `Dropbox (Personal)`,
- `Dropbox (Business-name)`

If I `cd Dropbox` it brings me inside my personal Dropbox but `pwd` gives `/Users/username/Dropbox` not `/Users/username/Dropbox (Personal)`, which is great. I would like to change this such that `cd Dropbox` brings me inside my business Dropbox instead though.

I can `cd` into my business account with `cd "Dropbox (Business-name)"` but would prefer to not have to do it that way for a number of reasons.

I haven't tried uninstalling and then reinstalling my personal Dropbox yet, that may switch the default command line `Dropbox` to the business account. If there isn't a better method I'll give this a try.

Comment: How about `cd 'drag folder to terminal'`

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. It is possible to point the symlink (purple `Dropbox` folder) to the business Dropbox folder instead by using this command:

```
ln -hfs "/Users/username/Dropbox (Business-name)" Dropbox
```

Now I can simply `cd Dropbox` which contains the content of my business Dropbox, and a `pwd` gives `/Users/username/Dropbox`.